# which normalization method is appropriate for regression problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, normalization, scales, data-preprocessing

I have a regression problem. I have 3 features:

$X_1$ is in the range $(0.7 , 1.3)$ 
$X_2$ is in the range $(0.4 , 0.5)$ 
$X_3$ is in the range $(4.5 , 5.5)$

and $Y$ is in the range $(115 , 719)$

I started trying linear regression without any normalization $R^2=0.15$. When I use Normalize with axis=0,  $R^2=0.5$ and when I Normalize with axis=1 I get $R^2=0.97$ and $MSE$ almost zero. But with using Scale and minmaz_scale $R^2$ is again around $0.15$.

I am not sure which one is correct? Especially with Normalize with axis=0 and axis=1 because the accuracy is totally different.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please display the linear regression models you are using.  (It sounds like some of them do not include a constant term.)

Comment: I used following regression model:
 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

and for normalization I used once:

dataset=preprocessing.normalize(dataset,'l2', axis=1) 
and once I used
dataset=preprocessing.normalize(dataset,'l2', axis=0) 

for accuracy I used:
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(Y_test, Y_pred)
and
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mean_squared_error(Y_test, Y_pred)